# Navigating back from multiple screen in React Native (IOS) using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Suppose i have four screens A -> B -> C -> D -> E , i want navigate back from E to C i use different routes itself for this purpose like ,
firstRoute => A -> B -> C is one route ,
secondRoute => D-> E is one more route.
i first switch the route to "firstRoute" then i take upon stack "C"
I do this as a reason because ,
i want to come to C from E using IOS back slide, after that when i use IOS back slide again, i should go back to B and followed by A rather than going back to E itself and making Infinite loop.
I am unable to do this task Can someone help me out in writing a example stack navigation and routes how to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.goBack()` of react-navigation!

like:

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => goBack()} title="Go back from this HomeScreen" />
        <Button onPress={() => goBack(null)} title="Go back anywhere" />
        <Button
          onPress={() => goBack('key-123')}
          title="Go back from key-123"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but it works only if you know the key of your **C** route!

you can see here for more details! 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back

Comment: goBack() works with android device back button or else UI generated button. If i am using IOS back slide which is gesture for ios. it just simply remove above stack which is accumulated. so that is not the reason i am asking this for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [switchNavigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav) combined with the original `stackNavigator`:

- put your A-B-C in a `stackNavigator`
- create a D' `switchNavigator` containing  D and E
- put that in your main `stackNavigator`, which will be A-B-C-D'

then

- navigate from A to B to C usualy
- from C you can use `.navigate(D)` as you would normally
- from D you can use `.navigate(E)` as you would normally

but as it is defined in a `switchNavigator`, no automatic navigation is allowed between its screens (this include Android backButton too), so :

- from E, going back will switch to C
- from D, going back will switch to C
- you can still manually switch from E to D using `.navigate(D)`

Just be aware that the default header back button in your D and E will too fall back on C

Hope this post was clear enought and helped you

Comment: Thanku so much for your thoughts and help . I will comeup with better clarity to ask you question about this.